# Java Sockets writing/reading

Tags: java, sockets, networking

So I want to read from socket , but it doesn't gives me anything , I am  newbie to java networking so please help me , it doesn't gives me any errors but doesn't gives me any output from client socket too... here is a source code:

```
ServerSocket server  = new ServerSocket(4444);
    Socket client = server.accept();
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
    String inputline = in.readLine();
    while(inputline != null)
    {
        System.out.println("recieved "+inputline);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
    server.close();
    client.close();
```

Comment: Is the client actually sending a line?

Comment: I don't even know really, :X

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You call readLine() exactly once. If it's not null on the first iteration, you've got an infinite loop (because it will forever be non-null). Be sure to update it.

Comment: I'm surprised that the OP did not spot that when stepping through with the debugger...

Comment: just add 
inputline = in.readLine();

after the print in the while loop